# Setting "Content-Length" header for large HTTP responses

Tags: java, http

I have a use case where I have HTTP responses that need to be sent out. The default behaviour as I understand is, that if the servlet engine is able buffer the whole response into it's buffer, it sets the `Content-Length` header equal to the size of the message, but in case it cannot, it goes ahead and sets `Transfer-Encoding` equal to `Chunked`. The size limit on which this is done is `8KB`. So, messages less than 8KB have `Content-Length` and others have `Transfer-Encoding`.

Now, I have a case where the HTTP response can be of 100s of MBs and I need to set `Content-Length` correctly, in order for the receiver to show a progress bar. So, my question is:

If the servlet buffer size is 8KB and for a 100MB response I set "Content-Length", does the servlet buffer the complete 100MB in memory before sending out the HTTP response? How is such a big message sent out when `chunked` is not set? Since, my current understanding is that both `Content-Length` and `chunked` cannot coexist.

Comment: No, you don't have to set a `Content-length` header, and if you do it will be ignored and overridden. Just set chunked transfer mode instead, or fixed-length transfer mode.

Comment: @user207421 Why and how will this be overridden??

Comment: By the process you mentioned in your question. It doesn't care that you set a `Content-length` header: it goes ahead and sets its own, unless you change the transfer mode. Given your requirement to show progress at the receiver I suggest fixed-length transfer mode. NB This is a transfer *mode*, not 'transfer encoding'.

Comment: @user207421 I can see a fixed-length at  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#fixedContentLength but how do I set a `fixed-length` mode to Response? Also, once this is set, how are the other headers of `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding` impacted?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was thinking in terms of a client. According to the `HttpServlet` documentation you *should* set the `Content-length` header.

Comment: @user207421 But then the original question comes back, right? If I set `Content-Length` then `Transfer-Encoding` does not get set, so how is such a big message buffered and sent?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong again, you should call `setContentLength()`. See the Javadoc for `HttpServlet`. If there is no `Transfer-encoding` there is no buffering and it all gets sent direct to the wire, i.e. in fixed-length streaming mode.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for the information. I just wanted to understand what sending directly to the wire means here. Is it no repeated 8KB buffering and it will just write all of my response in one go, which the client can then read with `fixed-length` stream? Are there any performance implications for this?

Comment: Not at all, it's actually quicker because there is no buffering latency. It's irritating that the `HttpServletResponse` API doesn't mirror `HttpURLConnection` in this matter.